# Question on characterization of $L^1 \subset L^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Yesterday in class, our professor mentioned the following:

> $(*)$ If $u \ge 0$ and $\int_\Omega u(x,\cdot)\;dx=k \;$ then classical
>   regularity theory implies ${\vert \vert u(\cdot,t) \vert
>  \vert}_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \le \hat k \quad \forall t\ge 0$

where $\Omega$ is a connected, bounded, closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$. As I was searching for some appropriate reference for $(*)$, I came across with the answer of Davide Giraudo in another question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205367/a-function-which-is-in-l1-but-does-not-belong-to-l-infty). he gave the following characterization of $L^1 \subset L^\infty$

> $(**)$ Let $(X,F,\mu)$ a measure space. We have $L^1(\mu)\subset
>  L^\infty(\mu)$ if and only if we can find a positive constant $c$ such
>   that for $A\in F$, either $\mu(A)=0$ or $\mu(A)\ge c$.

I believe there might be a relation between $(*)$ and $(**)$ which I can not see at this moment. I would appreciate much if somebody could explain why $(*)$ holds and why this result is implied by classical theory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $\hat{k}$? Do you have additional assumptions on $u$? Is it the solution of some differential equation? Otherwise I don't see a connection to "regularity theory".

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, $u$ satisfies the inhomogeneous heat equation $\partial_t u-\Delta u=f$ for some $f\in L^\infty$...$\hat k$ is just a constant for which I know nothing more

Comment: it seems that this characterization tells us that (*) cannot hold for general $u\in L^1$ if we can find sets with arbitrarily small measure in $\Omega$.